# How can I use the Android library ExtendedCalendarView

Tags: android

I am new in Android-Programming and I and my programmer team have to program a little app for our college. So we need the ExtendedCalendarView-Library and we already imported it in our AndroidStudio-project but we always get the same failure:

```
Can not find the following classes com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView
try to fix Build Path
```

and so on.

Code in our test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But we have imported another library at the same way and it works. We also get a suggestion from `com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.ExtendedCalendarView` when we open the '<' in a .xml file but always the same failure.

Meanwhile time is pressing so we have not so much time anymore.

Could anyone help us?

Comment: Can you rebuild your project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the provider tag in your android manifest if not then copy it in application tag of AndroidManifest:

```
<application>
...
    <provider
                android:name="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.CalendarProvider"
                android:authorities="com.tyczj.extendedcalendarview.calendarprovider" />

</application>
```